# How can I use environment variables to sign APK

Tags: android, apk, signing

I would like to sign an Android APK on travis.
To protect the keystore credentials I want to use environment variables.

Unfortunately I get following error when I try this

```
signingConfigs {
     release{
        storeFile file("path/to/release.keystore")
        storePassword $System.env.STOREPASS
        keyAlias "appAlias"
        keyPassword $System.env.KEYPASS
    }
}
```

> Error:(67, 0) Could not get unknown property '$System' for SigningConfig_Decorated{.....} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.SigningConfig.

Or is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can solve your problem.

```
signingConfigs {
     release{
        storeFile file("path/to/release.keystore")
        storePassword System.getenv("STOREPASS")
        keyAlias "appAlias"
        keyPassword System.getenv("KEYPASS")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following:

```
ext {
    travisBuild = System.getenv("TRAVIS") == "true"
}
```

in my root's `build.gradle` and then I'm using that property from the main module's `build.gradle` by:

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = !travisBuild
}
```

and it works ok.

You can get any other Travis environment variable the same way.

Regards!